# Are browser console errors a concern for QA

Tags: test-strategy

In my company's web app, pages will work fine but in the browser's developer tools, will show we're producing console errors.  The console errors could be something like a field is missing from some data structure. The code doesn't require it and moves on.

My developers assure me that these errors are not a concern and we don't need to remove them.  Indeed, they say some of these errors cannot be removed from the console. To be fair, they review the errors and fix those that need it.

I am a development manager with decades of experience. I am not in QA and I have no formal QA training.  To me, these console errors, however innocent, simply cause doubt, and doubt is a killer.  This all should be fixed.  But the lead UI dev is disagrees and is going to resist me. For these errors to be removed, I'll have to flex on my team, and I do not like flexing. So before I do, I need a reality check.

Answer (score 2):

The console will show what people want it to show.
It can display even an "the code passed here" as an error.

If people are showing non-erroneous messages as errors, there
is a problem in the quality of the feedback you get from your
software.

If the messages are really about problems,

As Lee said, it will depend.

What gets my attention the most is your phrase

> But the lead UI dev is disagrees and **is going to resist me**

"To resist someone" can be many things, but nonetheless the point is not for one side to win and the other lose, but to everyone understand the actual situation and make good decisions.

"The dev resists me" sound like you do not understand the situation, because the dev is trying to hide something or he/she is not able to explain to you (the higher decision maker) what is happening. Either way, I would make it clear that the current situation doesn't allow you to make clear decisions and assess, together with the dev, what steps you need to take - e.g., yourself skill-up on the technology/technical details, you do a code review, the team re-evaluate its TDD cycle and monitoring/alerting strategy (wich include the console errors), etc...

In summary, it seems you need gather the people and knowledge enough to (1) deeply understand the situation and (2) take a decision on what needs to change so the feedback from your software is effective.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, "It depends!" Your question also alludes to this. It also depends on perspective.

As a tester/quality engineer, yes, it can be important! Even as a developer, it's important to be aware of any messaging occurring in the browser console. I personally always have the browser console open when I am testing. This allows me to see errors/warnings when I find a bug, which will help in root cause analysis. I take this information and add it to the bug report. I also look at the network tab in DevTools for other errors.

Some devs I've worked with are surprised I do this and are usually appreciative of this. (The surprise is there if people assume all testers are only performing black-box testing, which isn't the case.)

While I don't have a number, there are a lot of people that do testing as an entryway into tech and don't get the training needed to consider looking at the browser console or how to utilize the DevTools. I recommend people learn this! There is so much information DevTools provides. So if you have anyone on your team doing testing work, and they are not familiar DevTools, I'd encourage you to get them some training here.

There can also be a lot of noise in the browser console from browser extensions. One area of improvement can be info logs. Some developers leave this here and they can be removed! The less noise the better as it'll make it easier to identify real problems! Some warnings can be left. But I'd argue that errors should be removed. Of course, any log info should be triaged to determine severity/priority/scope. Does any of this info cause any legal liability? Any data integrity issues? Will this information cause a hacker or nefarious actor to gain information for exploits? This is where security testing can help! These are only a few concerns I'd have if errors are not cleaned up.

It sounds like the developers on your team are arguing against "extra work" or only considering if they cause functionality issues. As noted, there are lots of non-functional reasons to fix them.

`they say some of these errors cannot be removed from the console` hmmm, I'd say this isn't really true. Errors can be removed, they just might not know how to remove them (an opportunity for training). Or, could be an error coming from a 3rd party dependency; in that case, they are right: it's not their responsibility to fix those. However, ensuring dependencies are up-to-date with the latest versions can help with this and is their responsibility. I'd recommend using tools like Synk or Renovate (other SAST tools) to help with dependency management and security scanning. Some of these tools can automate the upgrades of dependencies.

Another area of interest is "depreciation warnings." These often come about because the JavaScript, HTML, CSS features being used are older and will become deprecated soon! In order to meet modern standards, it takes awareness of seeing these in the browser console to make a recommendation to correct them.

From a user perspective, this may not matter. I doubt most users, especially non-technical users, have any knowledge of the browser console/DevTools, which also sounds like the argument your developers are pursuing. Users would only be aware of problems if it stops them from using the software.

I'd keep pursuing why they don't want to fix them to see what's really true. Using `5 Whys` concept can help to determine a reason.

I agree that leaving console logs can cause doubt (does this company care about quality?). It can look sloppy and unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

Console errors in the browser developer tools should be a concern for QA. While some errors may be benign and have no effect on user experience, others can be highly detrimental to the application's functionality and usability.

For instance, console errors that relate to missing fields or data structures can signify problems with the application's data processing, leading to incorrect data being displayed or processed. Such issues can result in a suboptimal user experience and a loss of trust in the application.

Console errors can also lead to performance issues. Also, dynamically generated elements may not appear properly and cause the UI to break.

Moreover, console errors can also indicate potential security vulnerabilities in the application. Attackers can use these errors to exploit the application and gain access to sensitive data.

As a development team, your responsibility is to ensure that the application meets quality standards and is reliable for users. Regularly reviewing and fixing console errors is essential to achieving these objectives. If you believe that these console errors need to be addressed, you should discuss this with the lead UI developer and provide examples of how these errors can impact the application's functionality and user experience.